# What Type of Joins are Supported in SOQL?

Tags: soql

There used to be a really great article I could link to when I wanted to describe (or even remember) the names of various joins in SOQL, their syntax, etc. However, the link died, and I have not found a replacement. The old link redirects to a [significantly less useful article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com), which doesn't even name any of the joins. The `Apex Developer Guide` doesn't really make sense as far as where to put this documentation, but that's where the redirect points to. Neither it nor the `SOQL and SOSL Reference` have any useful search results for `join` whatsoever.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to [tugce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/16280/tugce) for pointing out on Twitter the existence of web.archive.org, which has a [cached version](http://web.archive.org/web/20150910203534/https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) of the link in question. Using that, I was able to retrieve the old documentation. It seems valuable to preserve it here, which will make it more searchable in the future and preserve the useful content. I've tweaked the formatting slightly and corrected some typos, but otherwise posted the documentation here verbatim.

> ## SOQL Joins
>
> Let's look at what we can do with this data with some familiar JOIN patterns borrowed from SQL. This time however, we will utilize them in SOQL and also use the power of relationship traversal in path expressions that allow us to do joins implicitly.
>
> In each case below, we will use the pattern with respect to a query problem that we would like to express with SOQL. For Position, we will use `Position__c`, for Application we will use `Job_Application__c`, and for Candidate we will use `Candidate__c` in the corresponding code snippets.
>
> ### Right Outer Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find job Applications and related Departments (from Applications).
>
> Note that for this example, we would like to list applications including those which are not related to a Position yet. This is accomplished by an outer join.
>
> #### SOQL Query
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, Position__r.Department__c FROM Job_Application__c
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> List<Job_Application__c>
> APP-0001    Sales
> APP-0002    Sales
> APP-0003    null
> APP-0004    null
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> Note that we have utilized a path expression `Position__r.Deparment__c` to create a RIGHT JOIN between `Job_Application__c` and `Position__c`. The path expression allows us both to do the implicit join as well as extract the value of the `Department__c` field.
>
> ### Left Outer Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find all positions with their related list of applications.
>
> Again, we would like to list the positions regardless of whether there is a related application or not.
>
> #### SOQL Query
>
> ```
> SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Job_Applications__r) FROM Position__c
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> QA
> Programmer
> Evangelist       Job_Applications__r(1)  =>  APP-0001
> VP of Sales      Job_Applications__r(1)  =>  APP-0000
> Administrator
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> Note that we have utilized a NESTED select to obtain the records of related children from the parent. This kind of expression is very powerful in obtaining related records traversing from the 1 side in a 1-m relationship. In complex data modeling, especially with containment relationships, it is a useful pattern to obtain related information on a parent and all its children via traversing path expressions with relationship fields. In this example, we are utilizing a path expression from `Position__c` using the relationship, `Job_Applications__r` to obtain the list of applicants to create this join. This pattern will also be very useful in obtaining data from feeds in Chatter which will be discussed elsewhere. Please note that the result set is a list of positions where each position contains a list of application, reflecting the nature of the hierarchical representation of the data that is selected by this query.And is very useful Information for the beginners.
>
> ### Left Inner Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find names of all positions for which there are associated applications
>
> #### SOQL
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Position__c WHERE Id IN (
>     SELECT Position__c FROM Job_Application__c
> )
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> List<Position__c>
> Evangelist
> VP of Sales
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> [image: Spring 10] This is a very interesting case that illustrates a new Spring '10 feature. Previously, you would have to generate the list of Ids from `Job_Application__c` programmatically and test whether the Position Id existed in this list. Now, a SELECT statement in conjunction with an IN clause allows Force.com to generate the Ids directly from the `Job_Application__c` object in order to perform the join.
>
> ### Right Inner Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find all applications for positions that are in the 'Sales' department.
>
> #### SOQL
>
> ```
> SELECT Name,Position__r.Name,
> FROM Job_Application__c
> WHERE Position__r.Department__c = 'Sales'
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> List<Job_Application__c>
> APP-0000    VP of Sales    Sales
> APP-0001    Evangelist     Sales
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> In this case, we are again utilizing path expressions and relationships to allow us to get the results of a join. In addition, by constraining the value of `Department__c` field in `Position__c` (via `Position__r` relationship navigation) we are achieving an inner join.
>
> ### Left Anti Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find the name of all the positions which have no job applications.
>
> #### SOQL
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Position__c WHERE Id NOT IN (
>     SELECT Position__c FROM Job_Application__c
> )
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> List<Position__c>
> Administrator
> Programmer
> QA
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> [image: Spring 10] This use case is again utilizing a feature of the Spring '10 release, the ability to use a SELECT statement in conjunction with a NOT IN clause. See the section on Left Inner Join for the reverse example.
>
> ### Right Anti Join
>
> #### Problem
>
> Find the name of all applications for which there are no associated positions.
>
> #### SOQL
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Job_Application__c WHERE Position__c = null
> ```
>
> #### Results
>
> ```
> List<Job_Application__c>
> APP-0002
> APP-0003
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If you look closely, we are exploiting the way relationships are expressed with objects and field values here. Since this is a join from the m-1 side, the "join" is actually obtained by testing the value of the relationship field value, Position__c, with null, thus simulating a join without traversing the relationship.
>
> ---
>
> ### Cheat Sheet on Using Join Patterns
>
> Below is a cheat sheet for utilizing the Join patterns using a 1-m relationship. In this case, we are assuming that the parent object is on the left and the child object is on the right as in our example above.
> [image: SOQL Join Cheat Sheet]