# how to select all AccountId of the table X that is not in the table Y?

Tags: soql

I have a "table" Campaign Member in the Salesforce, with 2 records:

[image]

And I have a "table" Asset with 2 records too:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to select all AccountId of the table Asset that is not in the table Campaign Member.

For example, the query would return just the AccountId 111, because Account Id 870 there are in the table of Campaign Member.

Exist some way to make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might not work with `CampaignMember`, but the mechanisms you need for this are called table joins and anti-joins. It would look something like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Asset)
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM CampaignMember)
```

Comment: Should this be using related list relationship names (IIRC typically plural for standard object relationships) in the nested SELECTs?

Comment: @PhilW No, they operate like a top-level query.

Comment: You only use relationship names for joins in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Any chance you could link to some official documentation around a WHERE subquery/filter? I had never seen this before and googling only takes me to unofficial sources. I can't find it in the SOQL reference (but I may have simply missed it).

Comment: I [found it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?q=semi-join). The terms seem to be "semi-join" and "anti-join". Nice. I learned something new today :)

Comment: @PhilW If you haven't seen the old docs on joins, I scraped them for preservation and posted them [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/366360/2995).