# How to query Master object record only if they have a child record associated to it?

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

I want to filter out the contacts only if they have at least 1 serviceContract associated to it ?

I know this is possible using apex ( query all childs in inner query and iterate through using .size() operator.)
But is there any alternate to put this condition in SOQL itselsf ?

**Ex: Contact is a Parent and ServiceContracts are child to it.**

Say, Can I have any alternate to this query ?

> Select ID, (Select ID from ServiceContracts where size() >0) from
> contact limit 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM ServiceContract) LIMIT 10
```

`Limits.getQueries()` will return only 1 SOQL.

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) and make reference to the term "semi-join" to help understand what this is doing.

Comment: [Also useful](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/366360/2995).

Comment: N.B. Parent-Child subqueries and semi/anti joins don't count towards the 100 SOQL query limit, but they do count towards the lesser-known 300 "aggregate query" limit. `Limits.getAggregateQueries()` would return "1" here (as opposed to returning "0" if the semi-join in this answer were removed).