# Relationship query filtering

Tags: soql, query

In the example below, is it possible to filter only the Accounts that have a Contact that meets the Contact filter? As it is below it will only return Accounts where the Industry is 'media', but it will return Accounts that don't have a Contact that meets the CreateBy Alias requirement.

```
SELECT Name,
  (
    SELECT LastName
    FROM Contacts
    WHERE CreatedBy.Alias = 'x') 
 FROM Account WHERE Industry = 'media'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a **[`Left Inner Join`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/366360/2995)**:

```
SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE ...
AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE ...)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Is it possible to expand this to filter the Accounts that only have 1 Contact that matches the criteria?

Comment: If you wanted to do that type of filtering, you would need to do an `Aggregate` query on `Contact` where you `GROUP BY AccountId HAVING count(Id) = 1`.