# Nested SOQL is working but nested joins are not working

Tags: soql, nested

With Summer '23 release we can query upto 5 levels down in Parent-Child Relationships. See this [Salesforce release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_soql_5level.htm&release=244&type=5)

My sandbox is on Summer '23 release and I was able to test my custom objects successfully

```
SELECT Name, 
   (SELECT Name,
     (SELECT Id FROM MyObject1__r)
   FROM MyObject2__r)
FROM Contact
```

However, if I am querying using "IN" operator, I am getting an error. Looking at the errors they seem intentional but I am unable to understand why such SOQL with IN operators wont work

First Example

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact
WHERE (
            MyCustomCurrencyField__c >= 1000
)
AND (Id IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM MyObject2__r WHERE CustomBoolean__c = True))
AND (Id IN (SELECT MyObject2Field__r.Contact__c FROM MyObject1__r WHERE 
customNumberField__c > 2000))
```

Error: The inner select field 'MyObject2Field__r.Contact__c' cannot have more than one level of relationships

Second Example

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact
    WHERE (
            MyCustomCurrencyField__c >= 1000
          )
AND (Id IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM MyObject2__c WHERE CustomBoolean__c = True
    AND (Id IN (SELECT MyObject2Field__c FROM MyObject1__c WHERE 
customNumberField__c > 2000))
))
```

Error: Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

I am assuming with the latest release these joins should also work. I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it only works for the exact scenario described--you can now include sub-queries five levels deep in the *fields* part of the SOQL specification. It says nothing about additional subqueries being supported in SOQL, and this is congruent with the behavior of SOQL in every release of SOQL to date.

Comment: Alas, I wished nested joins worked. Thanks for the response @sfdcfox

Comment: Upon digging more I found this very useful explanation of how SOQL translates to joins. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366360/what-type-of-joins-are-supported-in-soql. It is clear to me now how joins work in SOQL.